# How do I book an Airport-Licensed Taxi to Toronto Pearson Airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, toronto

The [GTAA](https://www.torontopearson.com/en/toandfrom/taxilimo/#)  doesn't disclose:

1. how to book an Airport-Licensed Taxi TO the airport, or
2. which taxi companies fulfill their conditions beneath. How can I book in advance a taxi with the "GTAA number plate"?

> Airport licensed taxis and limos offer fair, flat rates to your destination and meet specific safety requirements. These are the only vehicles authorized to pick up fares from Toronto Pearson.
>
> A licensed taxi or limo:
>
> - Will pick up from the designated pick up area on the terminal curbs,    arrivals level
> - Will have a GTAA number plate on the bumper and decal on the window
> - Will have flat rate fare information in the vehicle
> - Will not pick up in the terminal or parking garages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no requirement that a taxi taking you TO Pearson airport be licensed, except in the general way that all taxis should be licensed if they act as taxis.

There is a special requirement that cabs picking you up FROM the airport be licensed by the GTAA, which is described on the site you linked to. That is because  a) picking up arriving passengers is when most of the scams happen b) they can check on it (it's almost impossible to police dropoffs).

If you have ordered a taxi from a licensed taxi firm to take you to the airport then you are not breaking any laws and neither are they. They don't need a special license.